# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid Argument: '\u202aC:/Users/.../Documents/Python/fish.jpg'

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, show

```
File = "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2580, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
```

This code works fine at my house, but fails with the title error on my student's computer. Windows 10. New installation of Python 3.7, new installation of Pillow through pip using the command prompt, new installation of Atom with the plugin "script". Anyone ever seen this happen before? (The below code is a simple image blend example).

(... represents the username folder, which is different on each computer.)

```
from PIL import Image

def main():

    size = width, height = 1080, 720

    imageOne = Image.open("C:/Users/.../Documents/Python/fish.jpg")
    imageTwo = Image.open("C:/Users/.../Documents/Python/tropicalfish.jpg")

    imageOne.thumbnail(size)
    imageTwo.thumbnail(size)

    imageOne.convert("RGB")
    imageTwo.convert("RGB")

    imageBlend = Image.blend(imageOne, imageTwo, .5)

    imageBlend.show()

    del imageOne, imageTwo, imageBlend

if (__name__ == "__main__"):

    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have \u202a character in your path. Try to remove some first letters and rewrite it manually. And try to use syntax like this `r'C:/Users/`.

About u202a - https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202a/index.htm

Comment: You don't need to use raw literals if you're using forward slashes as the directory separator.